# What is causing the array out of bounds error and how can I clean up my code?

Tags: java

This program is supposed to ascribe each letter of the alphabet its value in Scrable, take a text file, process the individual words, and print the word with the highest value average value (with the average value being the total value of all characters, letters and non-letters, divided by the number of those characters). My code seems almost complete but it reports an out of bounds error and I dont know why.

This is the error: `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -52`

This is the class driver:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class ScrabbleDriver{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    try{
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter text file ");
        String fileName = scan.next();
        Scrabble s = new Scrabble(fileName);
        s.readLines(); 
        s.report(); 
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);}
    }
}
```

This is the constructor class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Scrabble extends Echo {

    private int [] scores = {1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 8, 4, 10};
    private double maxScore = 0;
    private String maxScoreWord = " ";

    public Scrabble(String fn) throws IOException {
        super(fn);
    }

    public void processLine(String line) {
        line = line.toLowerCase();
        StringTokenizer s = new StringTokenizer(line);
        while (s.hasMoreTokens()) {
            processToken(s.nextToken());
        }
    }

    public void processToken(String token) {
        double wordScore = 0;
        for (int n = 0 ; n < token.length() ; n++) {
            char j = token.charAt(n);
            if ((j == '!') || (j == ',') || (j == '.'))
                wordScore = wordScore;
            else {
                int m = (int) (j - 'a');
                if (m <= 25) {
                    wordScore = wordScore + scores[m];
                }
            }
        }
        wordScore = (wordScore / token.length());
        if (wordScore > maxScore) {
            maxScore = wordScore;
            maxScoreWord = token;
        }
    }

    public void report() {
        System.out.print("Winner: " + maxScoreWord + "   " + "Score: " + maxScore);
    }
}
```

This is Echo class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Echo {

    String fileName; // external file name
    Scanner scan; // Scanner object for reading from external file

    public Echo(String fn) throws IOException {
        fileName = fn;
        scan = new Scanner(new FileReader(fileName));
    }

    public void readLines() { // reads lines, hands each to processLine
        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            processLine(scan.nextLine());
        }
        scan.close();
    }

    public void processLine(String line) { // does the real processing work
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

If any more info is needed, let me know.

Offending block

```
int m = (int)(j - 'a');
if(m <= 25){
```

#### wordScore = wordScore + scores[m];

```
}
```

Comment: how bout the error and the line nbr?

Comment: You can start from indentation. 4 `space` is equal to 1 `tab`.

Comment: Please post the stack trace; can't do much without that.

Comment: you don't know where the error is?

Comment: can you mention the line where you are getting the error

Comment: Lol you have no stacktrace?

Comment: this is the offending block of code guys:  `int m = (int)(j - 'a');
    if(m <= 25){
      wordScore = wordScore + scores[m];
    }`

Comment: @TMcKeown: You removed the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably `m` is negative. You only test against 25 or less.

Try to make sure that `j` (why name it `j`?) represents a letter before doing the calculation.

```
if (j < 'a' || j > 'z') {
    continue;
}
```

Or, alternatively, make sure that strange characters are not part of a "word" using the tokenizer. Depends on where you want to go with it.

Comment: Note that you can easily find this error by stepping through the method that generates the exception. Try to use a debugger as soon as possible.

Comment: the way I understand it as I have it, j - 'a' should yield the index in the array that the character held in j is located. if j is always (supposed to be) an alphabetic character or non-letter character, how can it ever be negative?

Comment: Well, it could be an uppercase character. There are many characters with a value less than `a`. Print them out, everything between `0x20` and `'a'` :)

Comment: I thought that might be the case but I implemented .toLowerCase() to make sure everything is set to lowercase

Comment: That leaves you with [quite a few other characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters) though. Why not just accept `a` to `z` (inclusive!). I.e. `if (j < 'a' || j > 'z') continue;`

Answer (score 2):

Your error is in `scores[m]`. If you select an array position beyond the length (or less than) of `scores`, then you will get an Out of Bounds Exception. You need to check the length of your array first. The calculation `j - 'a'` is producing a negative number.

Finally, ensure that `m` is not less than zero. You are checking if it is less than 25.

Here is a link to an [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/). There are `char` less than 'a' in the table. Therefore, you need to adjust your logic.

Since you are only working with presumably lower case letters, you need to make sure that your character value is between 97 and 122 before subtracting. So, you can compare the letters by saying:

```
if (j < 'a' || j > 'z')
{
   continue;
}
```

Comment: down voted because all you've done is describe what an `out of bounds` exception is.

Comment: @TMcKeown: No I didn't. That's the error. Did you not see that the calculation `j - 'a'` is negative?

Comment: I understand that, but I'm not sure where it is going "out of bounds." Did I not make the array 26 values long?

Edit: Sorry I just saw your responses. Why is j - 'a' negative?

Comment: @user3533405: I don't know what `j` is in your case, but you need to check if `m` is non-zero.

Comment: your calc is returning a negative number....  your if statement only protects for an index > 26

Comment: Negative numbers are always out of bounds. `j - 'a'` can be negative for characters with a lower character value than 'a' (and other than the divider and the characters you tested against).

Comment: j is supposed to represent any letter of the alphabet that is found in a provided text file, so a-z. Wouldn't m only be between 0 and 25?

Comment: @user3533405: Yes, but `A` is less than `a`. ASCII accounts for capital letters too.

Comment: what if the letter is capital?

Comment: @user3533405: By the way, I always subtract from ASCII `0`. This is a well known trick.

Comment: Doesn't .toLowerCase() in the extended processLine set the lines of the text file all to lowercase?

Comment: @user3533405: toLowerCase only works on letters. If you are getting -52, then you are subtracting a minus or hyphen.

Comment: Now I just commented that code 7 minutes ago... Oh, well, back to crypto :P

Comment: @owlstead: Oh sorry, I came to the realization without seeing your answer.

Comment: Never mind :), it's not rocket science to think of that statement, kudo's for going for the `continue`.

Comment: @owlstead: Have a great day!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, everyone! My mistakes are always the most obvious things -_-

Comment: @user3533405: Please be sure to check the checkmark for the answer that solved your problem.